# why the following list can not be convert to string array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

I have the following code in Java, when I run it, it give some error:

```
String[] stringArray1 = {"1","2","3"};
String[] stringArray2 = {"1","3","5"};
String[] stringArray3 = {"1","4","6"};

public String[] getString(int age) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        switch (age) {
            case 1:

                Collections.addAll(list, stringArray1);
                return composeStrings(list);

            case 2:

                Collections.addAll(list, stringArray2);
                return composeStrings(list);

            case 3:
                Collections.addAll(list, stringArray3);
                return composeStrings(list);

            default:
                return new String[]{"Not find", "Please specify the age"};
            }
    }

public String[] composeStrings(List<String> list) {

        list.add("added a new string");

        return (String[]) list.toArray();
}
```

but when I run it, it says line: `return (String[]) list.toArray();`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

what is the problem of this? and how to fix it?

Comment: Why are you returning `String[]`.. why not return `Collections.unmodifiableList(list); `

Comment: I need to get a string

Comment: This is very convoluted.. you create a List to just throw it away

Comment: Further reading on casting from Object[] to String[]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Arrays

Comment: You also are not checking the result of `addAll`

Comment: I used this list to add a new line of string, and then convert it to a string array, but how to check of addAll?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
public String[] composeStrings(List<String> list) {

    list.add("added a new string");

    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```

You can read the javadoc for toArray [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28%29)

Comment: Won't need the cast `(String[])`. Generic types are erased in the compiled code. By passing an object to `toArray` the component type String can be determined and returned. If the size fits, that new array is used as return value, after filling it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `String[]` as argument to `toArray()` method otherwise it will return you a `Object[]`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] stringArray1 = { "1", "2", "3" };
        String[] stringArray2 = { "1", "3", "5" };
        String[] stringArray3 = { "1", "4", "6" };

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        Collections.addAll(list, stringArray1);
        Collections.addAll(list, stringArray2);
        Collections.addAll(list, stringArray3);

        String[] finalArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        for (String item : finalArray) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have added the example code as well, now you can see there is no casting at all.